# Compare two files, remove line

Tags: bash, grep, awk

I have one file with URL's.
Example urls.txt:

```
https://www.indeed.co.uk/cmp/Endsleigh-Insurance/reviews?fcountry=ALL&fjobtitle=Claims+Assistant<br>
https://www.thestudentroom.co.uk/showthread.php?t=1063045
```

Have a second file with domain names only.
Example domains.txt:

```
remid.de
octc-china.com
crystalprod.cz
gesoc.org.mx
springbreakdirect.com
daytoncondohunters.com
automaxgroup.me
```

Is there any way to compare the files and remove urls that have same domain name from the second file
 
Like if urls.txt contain URL with any of domains from domains.txt remove it and save file.
I can do it with sed line by line but it will take quite a while.. 
Is ther any way to do it with grep or awk one command?

Answer (score 1):

found my own answer:

```
grep -F -vf domains.txt urls.txt
```